# Proving that a sequence is monotone

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Let $ \{s_m\}_{m=1}^\infty$ be the sequence defined:

$s_m = \sum_{k=1}^{m} \frac{1}{\sqrt{m^2 + k}}$

I have already proven that $s_m\to 1$ as $m\to \infty $ but i'm having trouble to show that $s_m$ is a monotonic sequence.

Would appreciate any help or advice, thanks in advance.

Comment: $$\begin{align}S_{n+1}&=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac1{\sqrt{(n+1)^2+k}}\\&=\frac1{\sqrt2(n+1)}+\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{\sqrt{(n+1)^2+k}}\\&=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{n\sqrt2(n+1)}+\frac1{\sqrt{(n+1)^2+k}}\\&>\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{\sqrt{n^2+k}}\\&=S_n\end{align}$$

Comment: Consider a term in the sequence: is $\frac{1} {\sqrt{m^{2} +k}} >0$ for all $m, k$? If so, then can you  see that $s_{m+1} =s_{m} + \frac{1} {\sqrt{(m+1)^{2} +(m+1)}} >s_{m}$?

Comment: @AloneAndConfused Why is your equality true? Each term in the sum defining $s_m$ is of the form $\frac{1}{\sqrt{m^2+k}}$. Each term in the sum defining $s_{m+1}$ is of the form  $\frac{1}{\sqrt{(m+1)^2+k}}$. *They depend on $m$*.

Comment: Ah yes - quite right @ClementC.- I had missed that!

Comment: By the inverse Laplace transform
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{m^2+k}} = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-sm^2}}{\sqrt{\pi s}}e^{-ks}\,ds \tag{1}$$
hence:

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{m}\frac{1}{\sqrt{m^2+k}} = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1-e^{-ms}}{(e^s-1)\sqrt{\pi s}}e^{-m^2 s}\,ds = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1-e^{-ms^2}}{e^{s^2}-1}e^{-m^2 s^2}\,ds\tag{2}$$

Comment: That provides al alternative way for bounding the involved sums. Not really simpler than the approach proposed by Simply Beautiful Art, but a but more general.

Comment: Actually Karamata's inequality provides a *way simpler* proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've spent too much time
on this already,
so I will just dump
everything new
into another answer.

First,

$\begin{array}\\
c_j
&=\binom{-1/2}{j}\\
&=\dfrac1{j!}\prod_{i=0}^{j-1} (-\frac12-i)\\
&=\dfrac{(-1)^j}{j!}\prod_{i=0}^{j-1} (\frac12+i)\\
&=\dfrac{(-1)^j}{2^jj!}\prod_{i=0}^{j-1} (1+2i)\\
&=\dfrac{(-1)^j\prod_{i=0}^{j-1} (2i+1)}{2^jj!}\\
&=\dfrac{(-1)^j\prod_{i=0}^{j-1} (2i+1)\prod_{i=1}^{j} (2i)}{2^jj!\prod_{i=1}^{j} (2i)}\\
&=\dfrac{(-1)^j(2j)!}{2^jj!2^j j!}\\
&=\dfrac{(-1)^j(2j)!}{4^jj!^2}\\
&=\dfrac{(-1)^j}{4^j}\binom{2j}{j}\\
&\approx \dfrac{(-1)^j}{4^j}\dfrac{4^j}{\sqrt{\pi j}}\\
&= \dfrac{(-1)^j}{\sqrt{\pi j}}\\
\end{array}
$

Note that
$\dfrac{c_{j+1}}{c_j}
=\dfrac{\dfrac1{(j+1)!}\prod_{i=0}^{j} (\frac12+i)}{\dfrac1{j!}\prod_{i=0}^{j-1} (\frac12+i)}
=\dfrac{j+\frac12}{j+1}
=1-\dfrac{1}{2(j+1)}
$
so the
$c_j$ is decreasing.

Now we can get
an infinite converging series
for $s_m$.

$\begin{array}\\
s_m 
&= \sum_{k=1}^{m} \frac{1}{\sqrt{m^2 + k}}\\
&= \frac1{m}\sum_{k=1}^{m} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + k/m^2}}\\
&= \frac1{m}\sum_{k=1}^{m} (1 + k/m^2)^{-1/2}\\
&= \frac1{m}\sum_{k=1}^{m} \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \binom{-1/2}{j}(k/m^2)^j\\
&= \frac1{m}\sum_{k=1}^{m} \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} (-1)^jc_j(k/m^2)^j\\
&= \frac1{m}\sum_{k=1}^{m} \left(1+\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} (-1)^jc_j(k/m^2)^j\right)\\
&= 1+\frac1{m}\sum_{k=1}^{m} \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} (-1)^jc_j(k/m^2)^j\\
&= 1+\frac1{m} \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{m} (-1)^jc_j(k/m^2)^j\\
&= 1+\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}(-1)^jc_jm^{-2j-1}\sum_{k=1}^{m} k^j\\
&= 1+\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}(-1)^jc_jp_j(m)/m^{2j+1}
\qquad\text{where } p_j(m)=\sum_{k=1}^{m} k^j\\
&= 1+ \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}(-1)^jc_jp_j(m)/m^{2j+1}\\
\end{array}
$

Since,
for $j=1, 2, 3, ...$
we have
$c_j
=\frac12, \frac38, \frac{5}{16}, ...
$
and
$p_j(m)
=\frac12 m(m+1),
\frac16 m(m+1)(2m+1),
\frac14 m^2(m+1)^2
$,
we have

$\begin{array}\\
s_m
&=1
-\frac{m(m+1)}{4m^3}
+\frac{3m(m+1)(2m+1)}{8\cdot 6m^5}
-\frac{5m^2(m+1)^2}{16\cdot 4m^7}
+...\\
&=1
-\frac{m+1}{4m^2}
+\frac{(m+1)(2m+1)}{16m^4}
-\frac{5(m+1)^2}{64m^5}
+...\\
\end{array}
$

Note that since
$c_j 
\approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi j}}
$
and
$p_j(m)
\approx
\frac{m^{j+1}}{j+1}
$
we have
$c_jm^{-2j-1}p_j(m)
\approx \dfrac{1}{m^{j}(j+1)\sqrt{\pi j}}
$,
so the series converges
absolutely.

From this,
we can get an exact equation for
$s_{m+1}-s_m
$.

We first will use the
expression with the
first 4 terms.

$\begin{array}\\
s_{m+1}-s_m
&=(1
-\frac{m+2}{4(m+1)^2}
+\frac{(m+2)(2m+3)}{16(m+1)^4}
-\frac{5(m+2)^2}{64(m+1)^5}
+...)\\
&\qquad
-(1
-\frac{m+1}{4m^2}
+\frac{(m+1)(2m+1)}{16m^4}
-\frac{5(m+1)^2}{64m^5}
+...)\\
&=-(\frac{m+2}{4(m+1)^2}-\frac{m+1}{4m^2})
+(\frac{(m+2)(2m+3)}{16(m+1)^4}-\frac{(m+1)(2m+1)}{16m^4})\\
&\qquad
-(\frac{5(m+2)^2}{64(m+1)^5}-\frac{5(m+1)^2}{64m^5})
+...\\
&=\frac{m^2 + 3 m + 1}{4 m^2 (m + 1)^2}
-\frac{4 m^5 + 19 m^4 + 30 m^3 + 20 m^2 + 7 m + 1}{16 m^4 (m + 1)^4}\\
&\qquad +\frac{5  (3 m^6 + 17 m^5 + 35 m^4 + 35 m^3 + 21 m^2 + 7 m + 1)}{64 m^5 (m + 1)^5}\\
&=\frac{16m^3(m+1)^3(m^2 + 3 m + 1)
-4m(m+1)(4 m^5 + 19 m^4 + 30 m^3 + 20 m^2 + 7 m + 1)+5  (3 m^6 + 17 m^5 + 35 m^4 + 35 m^3 + 21 m^2 + 7 m + 1)}{64 m^5 (m + 1)^5}\\
&=\frac{4 m (m + 1) (4 m^6 + 16 m^5 + 13 m^4 - 10 m^3 - 16 m^2 - 7 m - 1)+5  (3 m^6 + 17 m^5 + 35 m^4 + 35 m^3 + 21 m^2 + 7 m + 1)}{64 m^5 (m + 1)^5}\\
&=\frac{m^5 (16 m^3 + 80 m^2 + 131 m + 52)+O(m^4)}{64 m^5 (m + 1)^5}\\
&=\frac{16 m^3 + 80 m^2 + 131 m + 52)+O(1/m)}{64 (m + 1)^5}\\
&\gt\frac{16 (m+1)^3+O(1/m)}{64 (m + 1)^5}\\
&\gt\frac{1+O(1/m^4)}{4(m + 1)^2}\\
\end{array}
$

Next,
look at all the terms.

$\begin{array}\\
s_{m+1}-s_m
&= \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}(-1)^jc_j\left(\dfrac{p_j(m+1)}{(m+1)^{2j+1}}-\dfrac{p_j(m)}{m^{2j+1}}\right)\\
&= \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}(-1)^jc_j\left(\dfrac{p_j(m+1)m^{2j+1}-p_j(m)(m+1)^{2j+1}}{(m+1)^{2j+1}m^{2j+1}}\right)\\
&= \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}(-1)^jc_j\left(\dfrac{d_j(m)}{(m+1)^{2j+1}m^{2j+1}}\right)\\
\end{array}
$

where 
$d_j(m)=p_j(m+1)m^{2j+1}-p_j(m)(m+1)^{2j+1}
$.

$\begin{array}\\
d_j(m)
&=p_j(m+1)m^{2j+1}-p_j(m)(m+1)^{2j+1}
\\
&=(p_j(m)+(m+1)^j)m^{2j+1}-p_j(m)(m+1)^{2j+1}\\
&=(p_j(m)+(m+1)^j)m^{2j+1}-p_j(m)(m+1)^{2j+1}
\\
&=p_j(m)(m^{2j+1}-(m+1)^{2j+1})+(m+1)^jm^{2j+1}\\
\\
&=p_j(m)m^{2j+1}(1-(1+1/m)^{2j+1})+(m+1)^jm^{2j+1}\\
\\
&=m^{2j+1}(p_j(m)(1-(1+1/m)^{2j+1}))+(m+1)^j)\\
&\lt m^{2j+1}(p_j(m)(1-(1+(2j+1)/m)))+(m+1)^j)\\
&= m^{2j+1}(p_j(m)(-\frac{2j+1}{m})+(m+1)^j)\\
&\approx m^{2j+1}(-m^{j+1}\frac{2j+1}{m(j+1)}+(m+1)^j)
\qquad\text{since }p_j(m)>n^{j+1}/(j+1)\\
&= m^{2j+1}(-m^{j}\frac{2j+1}{(j+1)}+(m+1)^j)\\
&= m^{3j+1}(-\frac{2j+1}{j+1}+(1+1/m)^j)\\
&\approx m^{3j+1}(-2+\frac1{j+1}+(1+1/m)^j)\\
\end{array}
$

so if
$(1+1/m)^j
\lt 2-\frac1{j+1}
$
then
$d_j(m) < 0$.

This is the same as
$1+1/m
\lt (2-\frac1{j+1})^{1/j}
$
or
$m
\gt \frac1{(2-\frac1{j+1})^{1/j}-1}
$.

Numerically,
according to Wolfy,
this looks like about
$3j/2$.
To check:

$\begin{array}\\
(2-\frac1{j+1})^{1/j}
&=2^{1/j}(1-\frac1{2j+2})^{1/j}\\
&=2^{1/j}e^{\ln(1-1/(2j+2))/j}\\
&\approx 2^{1/j}e^{-1/(j(2j+2))}\\
&=e^{\ln 2/j-1/(j(2j+2))}\\
&=e^{\ln 2/j-1/(j(2j+2))}\\
&\approx 1+\ln 2/j-1/(j(2j+2))\\
\text{so}\\
\frac1{(2-\frac1{j+1})^{1/j}-1}
&\approx \frac1{\ln 2/j-1/(j(2j+2))}\\
&= \frac{j}{\ln 2-1/(2j+2)}\\
\text{and}\\
\frac1{\ln 2}
&\approx 1.44\\ 
\end{array}
$

Experiments with Wolfy
suggest that
a more accurate approxumation
is
$\frac{j}{\ln 2-1/(3.85j)}
$.

Estimating the terms.

Each term in the sum
is about

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{d_j(m)}{(m+1)^{2j+1}m^{2j+1}}
&\approx \dfrac{m^{3j+1}(-1+\frac1{j+1}+\frac{j}{m})}{(m+1)^{2j+1}m^{2j+1}}\\
&\approx -\dfrac{m^j(1-\frac1{j+1})}{(m+1)^{2j+1}}\\
&\approx -\dfrac{1-\frac1{j+1}}{m^{j+1}}\\
\end{array}
$

Taking $c_j$ into account,
this is about
$-\dfrac{c_j(1-\frac1{j+1})}{m^{j+1}}
$

This is certainly
decreasing in absolute value,
so the sum will be
between the last two sums.

Answer (score 0):

By way of making up for my earlier error (note to self: don't math late at night!), here is another attempt. We have

$$S_{n} \,=\, \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+k}} \,=\, \underbrace{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+2}} + \cdots + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n}}}_{n \text{  terms} }.$$

From here it should be clear that

$$\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+n}} \,=\, \frac{n}{\sqrt{n(n+1)}} \,<\, S_{n} \,<\, \frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+1}} \qquad \forall\,n\in\mathbb{N}.$$

You may already have this bound as you mention you have shown $S_{n}\rightarrow 1$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$; this follows from above and the Squeeze theorem. Using this, we also have

$$S_{n+1}\,>\,\frac{n+1}{\sqrt{(n+1)(n+2)}}. $$

Since all the terms in the inequalities are positive, we have:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{S_{n+1}}{S_{n}} &\,>\, \frac{n+1}{\sqrt{(n+1)(n+2)}}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{n(n+1)}}{n} =  \sqrt{\frac{n(n+1)^{3}}{n^{2}(n+1)(n+2)}\,} =  \sqrt{\frac{n(n+1)^{2}}{n^{2}(n+2)}\,} \\[0.2cm]
&\,=\, \sqrt{\frac{n^{3}+2n^{2}+n}{n^{3}+2n^{2}}\,} = \sqrt{1+\frac{n}{n^{3}+2n^{2}}\,} \,>\, 1.
\end{align}$$

Since $S_{n}>0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, we have (after multiplication by $S_{n}$) that $S_{n+1}>S_{n}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and hence $(S_{n})$ is monotonically increasing.

Comment: I don't think so. All you can deduce is that $S_{n+1}-S_n > \frac{n+1}{\sqrt{(n+1)(n+2)}}-\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}$.

Comment: Perhaps, but I can't see where I have gone wrong in my working. More than happy to be shown otherwise - it is how we learn after all!

Comment: You used the lower bound for both. But if you want to get a lower bound for a-b, you need to use the lower bound for a and the upper bound for b.

Comment: Yes! Quite obvious once it's pointed out. Thanks @marty-cohen

Answer (score 0):

The power series for
$(1+x)^{-1/2}$
with $0 < x < 1$
is an enveloping series,
in that its sum is between
any two consecutive finite sums.

Since
$(1+x)^{-1/2}
=1-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{3x^2}{8}-\frac{5x^3}{16}+...
$
we have
$1-\frac{x}{2}
\lt (1+x)^{-1/2}
\lt 1-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{3x^2}{8}
$
or
$(1+x)^{-1/2}
=1-\frac{x}{2}+ax^2
$
where
$0 < a < \frac38
$.
This is our basic inequality.

Note:
All the $a$ and $a_m$
in what follows are
values satisfying
$0 < a < \frac38$.

$\begin{array}\\
s_m 
&= \sum_{k=1}^{m} \frac{1}{\sqrt{m^2 + k}}\\
&= \frac1{m}\sum_{k=1}^{m} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + k/m^2}}\\
&= \frac1{m}\sum_{k=1}^{m} (1 + k/m^2)^{-1/2}\\
&= 1-\frac1{2m}\sum_{k=1}^{m} 
(k/m^2)+\frac1{m}\sum_{k=1}^{m}a_k(k/m^2)^2\\
&= 1-\frac{m(m+1)}{4m^3}+a_m\frac{m(m+1)(2m+1)}{6m^5}\\
&= 1-\frac{m+1}{4m^2}+a_m\frac{(m+1)(2m+1)}{6m^4}\\
\end{array}
$

In what follows,
"(W)" means that
Wolfy helped.

$\begin{array}\\
s_{m+1}-s_m
&=(1-\frac{m+2}{4(m+1)^2}+a_{m+1}\frac{(m+2)(2m+3)}{6(m+1)^4})-(1-\frac{m+1}{4m^2}+a_m\frac{(m+1)(2m+1)}{6m^4})\\
&=\frac{m+1}{4m^2}-\frac{m+2}{4(m+1)^2}+a_{m+1}\frac{(m+2)(2m+3)}{6(m+1)^4}-a_m\frac{(m+1)(2m+1)}{6m^4}\\
&=\frac{m^2 + 3 m + 1}{4 m^2 (m + 1)^2}+a_{m+1}\frac{(m+2)(2m+3)}{6(m+1)^4}-a_m\frac{(m+1)(2m+1)}{6m^4}
\qquad\text{(W)}\\
&\gt\frac{m^2 + 3 m + 1}{4 m^2 (m + 1)^2}-\frac38\frac{(m+1)(2m+1)}{6m^4}\\
&=\frac{2 m^4 + 5 m^3 - 5 m^2 - 5 m - 1}{16 m^4 (m + 1)^2}
\qquad\text{(W)}\\
&\gt 0\\
\end{array}
$